# Not showing private key under certificate with disclosure arrow

Tags: iphone, certificate, keychain

I have the certificates and keys on my new mac machine but when i going to upload my application it giving me the error **Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXXX' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain.***

Then I googled out then find that it required to **verify the keychain configuration**.

I noticed that  their is **no Grey Disclosure Triangles to the left of your iPhone Certificates to confirm  Private Keys are present**. So i try to import it but it gives me error that **Unable to import an item .The contents of this item cannot be retrieved.** I also tried using command line command then also not adding the private keys under certificate.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have revoked the both certificates it solved my problem.

Comment: Revoking might not be an option when you work for a company and you revoking the certificate may result in disruption on the work of other.

Answer (score 2):

Not applicable to the original question, but a similar problem that brought me here: You need to have the "Certificates"  or "My Certificates" category selected (in the leftmost pane), rather than "All items". Certificates will be listed with "All items" selected, but they won't have the disclosure triangle.